# Beam on SparkRunner overwriting its own output

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam, parquet

I'm running a Beam pipeline on a SparkRunner, with Parquet file outputs (though the issue is there if I'm doing other IO outputs). The issue I'm having is that on output, the file copy is overwriting its own output. Here's the log output:

```
19/10/22 18:26:35 INFO FileBasedSink: Will copy temporary file FileResult{tempFilename=/home/hadoop/just1hour/.temp-beam-357d6916-5d8e-4519-a7a4-3852249011b5/77100cd1-04ae-441c-848f-e0d0067feeb8, shard=0, window=org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.GlobalWindow@5316e95f,
 paneInfo=PaneInfo.NO_FIRING} to final location /home/hadoop/just1hour/output-00000-of-00001
19/10/22 18:26:35 INFO FileBasedSink: Will copy temporary file FileResult{tempFilename=/home/hadoop/just1hour/.temp-beam-357d6916-5d8e-4519-a7a4-3852249011b5/f19819df-e006-431a-8ccd-6e67af692c3e, shard=0, window=org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.GlobalWindow@5316e95f,
 paneInfo=PaneInfo.NO_FIRING} to final location /home/hadoop/just1hour/output-00000-of-00001
19/10/22 18:26:35 INFO FileBasedSink: Will copy temporary file FileResult{tempFilename=/home/hadoop/just1hour/.temp-beam-357d6916-5d8e-4519-a7a4-3852249011b5/cb2abe0c-8cc2-4a94-ae54-97b67c5e7d20, shard=0, window=org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.GlobalWindow@5316e95f,
 paneInfo=PaneInfo.NO_FIRING} to final location /home/hadoop/just1hour/output-00000-of-00002
19/10/22 18:26:35 INFO FileBasedSink: Will copy temporary file FileResult{tempFilename=/home/hadoop/just1hour/.temp-beam-357d6916-5d8e-4519-a7a4-3852249011b5/611d194a-4e8f-44bc-8776-4bc2c55a8f34, shard=1, window=org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.windowing.GlobalWindow@5316e95f,
 paneInfo=PaneInfo.NO_FIRING} to final location /home/hadoop/just1hour/output-00001-of-00002
```

As you can see the the first file is being overwritten.

I was able to workaround this by manually specifying the number of shards to be equal to the number of input files, but I'm wondering if there's some other config that could explain or avert this behavior.

Edit:

This is a batch job and here's the code that generates the output:

```
p.apply(TextIO.read().from(input).withDelimiter("{".getBytes()))
                .apply(Filter.by((String record) -> !record.isEmpty()))
                .apply(ParDo.of(new ParseNotificationJSON())).setCoder(AvroCoder.of(SCHEMA))
                .apply("Write Parquet files",
                        FileIO.<GenericRecord>write().via(ParquetIO.sink(SCHEMA)).to(output));

        p.run().waitUntilFinish();
```

Comment: Is it a batch or stream processing job? Also, it would be good if you can provide a minimal code block so that the issue can be re-produced.

Comment: Added that info above.

Answer (score 0):

FileIO based sinks in Beam overwrite the files if any file has same name in the target directory. The default file naming for Bounded sources also uses shard-Index and shard-number in the file names hence using `.withNumShards(0)` will use the runner determined sharding. If you use `.withNumShards(0)` in your sink it should work fine.

Comment: No, that doesn't work-- the same behavior persists. The problem seems to be that each set of shards doesn't seem to know about the others. In the example log output, the very first shard outputs to output-00000-of-00001, then the next shard overwrites the first shard. The second set of shards is ok because they're writing to output-00000-of-00002 and output-00001-of-00002.